# Unity alongside Gnome 3

Tags: unity, gnome

I'm currently running Ubuntu Gnome. I'm wondering if it is possible to install Unity so that I can choose which one I want at the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

You can install `unity` by running:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

You can find all the available X sessions that you can log into in `/usr/share/xsessions` directory.